# Collection view drag and drop with creating "folders" by overlapping two cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

How to implement a UICollectionView drag and drop interface where users can hold one cell over the other to create a new collection, like on the iOS home screen?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806546/uicollectionview-drag-and-drop-folder-creation